# The replace function is not working as expected?

Tags: replace

.replace only recognising last occurrence of the code. Only works for input he. Not sure why. Can recode with conditionals etc. but curious to know why the code doesn’t work as is. Thanks.

## Input His get His

## Input he get she

```
maleReport = str(input("Please enter the male report. "))

femaleReport = maleReport.replace("His","Her")
femaleReport = maleReport.replace("He","She")
femaleReport = maleReport.replace("his","her")
femaleReport = maleReport.replace("he","she")

print ("The female comment is:")
print (femaleReport)
```

Comment: You might consider tagging this with the appropriate coding language.  For example, is this Python?

Comment: you're replacing words in `male` variable and assigning to `female`, so every assignment effectively discards previous replacement, you can use `female` variable after first assignment, but it will create another problem, first replace will change `His` to `Her`, second will change `He` part of `Her` to `She`, turning it into `Sher`